# Saving and retrieving .avi file from Oracle 11g using c#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, blob

I want to save in a table from my database an .avi file using c# and Oracle 11g.

The table is a simple one

```
CREATE TABLE  VIDEOS
(
   id number,
   description varchar2(20), 
   video ORDSYS.OrdVideo 
);
```

The thing I am doing is using a form in c# get some fields and call a procedure from the Oracle db

The procedure is

```
create or replace
procedure inserareVideoBD(vid in number, vdescriere in varchar2, nfis in varchar2 )
is
begin 
    declare
        obj ORDSYS.ORDVideo;
        ctx RAW (64):=NULL;
    begin
        insert into videos values (vid, vdescriere, ordsys.ordvideo.init('FILE', 'DIR', nfis));
    commit;
    end;
end;
```

// to mention that the DIR file was already assigned and the db has access to it because the images that I save almost the same way work

---

So after the video is saved I want to retrieve it using this procedure

```
create or replace
procedure FETCHERVIDEO (vid in number, flux out blob, descriere out varchar2)
is
begin
declare
obj ordsys.ordvideo;
mimeType VARCHAR2(4000);
format VARCHAR2(31);
ctx RAW(64) :=NULL;
begin 
select video into obj from videos where id=vid;
 DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(flux, true, 10);
 obj.getContentInLob(ctx,flux, mimeType,format);
select description into descriere from videos where id=vid;

end;
end;
```

---

After the video is saved I want to play it using windows media player. This is the code that want's to accomplish that

```
OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand("fetchervideo", con);
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd1.Parameters.Add("vid", OracleDbType.Int32);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("flux", OracleDbType.Blob);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("descriere", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 255);

                cmd1.Parameters[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                cmd1.Parameters[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd1.Parameters[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

//get video id
                cmd1.Parameters[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem);


                try { cmd1.ExecuteScalar(); }
                catch (OracleException exc) { Mesaj2.Text = "Mesaj: " + exc.Message; }

                OracleBlob var = (OracleBlob)cmd1.Parameters[1].Value;
                byte[] blob = new Byte[var.Length];
                File.WriteAllBytes(@"c://temp_mvi.avi", blob);

                try
                {
                    player.URL = "c://temp_mvi.avi";
                    player.Ctlcontrols.play();
                }
```

---

The problem is that the file is saved at the specified path but it can't be played while the original file that was uploaded was playing on the same player.

Am I missing something can anybody give some better idea.
Every response is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a web application , i think you need to specify the content type on the html side so it can show the content accordingly.